# What checks do I need to login a user with PHP?

Tags: php, security, authentication

I'm attempting to write a page that allows a user to remain logged in. Is it simply enough to set a session variable if the site has SSL? I am checking for a session variable that just says the person is logged in.

```
 $_SESSION['LOGIN'] = true;
```

On each page, I simply check to see if this value is set. If so, let them have access. If not, kick them back to login. Is this enough security wise with SSL? Or are there any other checks I should be doing?

Comment: It is not enough to distinguish whether the user is logged or not. You usually will need to have an identifier to distinguish every user ($_SESSION['idUser']). This session var can also serve to store if the user has been logged or not (ej: zero means no user logged).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sessions are stored on the server so SSL would not matter in this case. SSL protects the user from being deceived when a proxy replaces the page in transit with it's own to steal info. SSL prevents this by encrypting the page. The session is never transmitted. This would be enough, but if you want to be really safe, you can re perform authentication every page load with the username and password stored in the session.

Answer (score 1):

If your system allows only registered users, i.e. everyone must enter authentication, then you need to ensure the following:

1. When a user logs in: enter username and password and clicks enter, if they click the back button (on the browser) they are automatically logged off. If not, someone could log on, click the back button and interpret they are logged off, leave their desk and someone else clicks the forward button and gains unauthorized access.
2. When a user logs off, if they click the back button they are re-directed to the index page. If not, someone could log off, leave their desk, someone else clicks the back browser button and gain access to the system.

Comment: For me this would be a strange behavior, why should i be logged off pressing the back button? How would you even determine that the back button was pressed? People can also forget to log off elsewhere, then it's better when you have a timeout of the session (what is the standard behavior). I think it would be more helpful, to display the login/logoff state prominent on every page, so users can find it easily and have a reminder of the state.

Comment: Think about it. It's a secure site! if you log in, and click the browser's back button you should be logged off otherwise it's possible someone could click the forward button and gain access to the system. Try login into email and clicking back and see if you're logged off.

Comment: I"m not saying this is the main log off. You should have a log off button on your page. But just if the user initially logs in from the authentication area and clicks the back button should log off : just for this page only

Comment: Actually not even my finance portal does a log off, when you click the back button or visit an external page (just tried it). How should it know you pressed the back button? I think people know that after a login they have to logout, and when you close the browser, the session cookie is gone anyway.

Comment: Not necessarily. This is one security issue for systems studying post graduate studies today. From what I remember I got it done by developing an algorithm with sessions. Look lets be real here. If its not implemented then there's a 1% chance that someone would hack into another's account. a 1% chance means out of every 1000 users, there would be at least 10 which is many. I'm just suggesting if you require a higher level of security. Trust me, there's a way to do it. I got it done a few years aback.

Comment: The issue doesn't center around what the user know he/she is doing. It's focusing on a mistake by the user. In 2001 I sat by a public computer, the browser was on the login page of a very popular email service, I clicked the forward button and I gained access into someone's account all because the back button was clicked and they assumed they were logged off..... but in reality they were not because I was looking at their inbox ... and yes I clicked log out. Ask yourself this question: what if that person's account had very sensitive information? -> blackmail, bribery etc etc etc